# How can I download Linux on my Toshiba laptop, where windows 7 just died?

Tags: system-installation

I have two laptops, and one is working fine with windows 7. Thew other just  died, and I decided to try Linux on that. The computer is working, and I can access the boot menu, but it wont start windows anymore. How can I install Linux on that computer? I have no files or apps that I need to keep on that laptop.

Thank you

Comment: Come on, there are tons of tutorials around the internet (including Ubuntu Official Documentation), just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu is easy! First,

**Grab Your Gear**

You'll need a blank USB drive with at least 2 GB of free space on it.

Now download your prefered version of Ubuntu (currently 14.04.3 LTS or 15.10) http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

And finally grab the Universal USB Installer program: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

**Creating a Startup Disk**

1. Plug in your USB drive
2. Open the Universal USB Installer
3. Select 'Ubuntu' as the distribution, select your .iso file, select your USB drive, and click Create.

**Booting from USB**

Here's where it gets a little tricky. Every computer is different, so I can't give exact instructions. When turning your computer on, look for the boot selection screen. Not all computers have one.

If you don't have one, enter BIOS (usually F2 or F8), enable USB boot if needed, and re-arrange your boot options so that USB drive is at the top. Now reboot your computer with the USB drive plugged in, and you should boot into the installer.

**Installing Ubuntu**

The installer may take some time to load, but once it does, it will give you step-by-step instructions on how to install Ubuntu. Since you don't have anything else on the laptop, you can select the option to erase everything and install Ubuntu.

And that's it! The rest of the instructions are in the installer, and everything else should work like a charm! Unless, of course, it doesn't, in which case we'll be here to help with any problems.